# Impossible to properly center my app bar in flutter

Tags: android, flutter, dart, appbar, flutter-appbar

In my app, I am trying to add a navbar and this working fine but I cannot force the navbar in the top | center of the screen. I have tried to customize it with blur effect in background and the goal was to make the background size of the same size of the 2 Text I have inside. It's kind of working but forcine the bar to be aligned left instead of being centered. When I try to center it, the text widgets are now centered but the backgound is using the entire width of the display.

Below is the code. I removed some useless part to make it easier to read

```
return Scaffold(
      extendBodyBehindAppBar: true,
      backgroundColor: Colors.grey,
      appBar: AppBar(
        elevation: 0,
        backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
        title: ClipRRect(
            borderRadius:
                const BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(FizzinConstants.radius)),
            child: BackdropFilter(
                filter: ImageFilter.blur(
                  sigmaX: 15.0,
                  sigmaY: 25.0,
                ),
                child: Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                  mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                  children: [
                    GestureDetector(...),
                    GestureDetector(...),
                  ],
                ))),
      ),
```

Any idea how to center it and keeping the background of the size of the child ?

Thanks

Comment: Can you provide some screenshot with how it's looking now and how it should be looking ?

Comment: Please share the desired output , also refer to my [answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76597279/4370398).

Answer (score 0):

Refer below code:

[image: Wrap width of child]

```
return Scaffold(
  extendBodyBehindAppBar: true,
  backgroundColor: Colors.white,
  appBar: AppBar(
    leadingWidth: 8,
    elevation: 0,
    backgroundColor: Colors.red,
    title: Stack(
      children: [
        Center(
          child: ClipRRect(
            borderRadius: const BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(16)),
            child: BackdropFilter(
              filter: ImageFilter.blur(
                sigmaX: 15.0,
                sigmaY: 25.0,
              ),
              child: Wrap(
                children: [
                  Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                    mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                    children: [
                      TextButton(
                        child: Text("Tab A",style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),),
                        onPressed: () {},
                      ),
                      TextButton(
                        child: Text(" Tab B",style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),),
                        onPressed: () {},
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    ),
  ),
);
```